# Facebook 'Like' button cut off

Tags: css, facebook

I'm currently developing a small website and I want to integrate a facebook 'Like' button. I copied and pasted the automatically generated code that they proveide on their website and the button is just cut off. As in the following picture:

[image]

The code they provided is the following:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width=235&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:25px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I don't have any CSS code apllied to it either. Any idea on how to solve this question?

Comment: We probably need to see the code for the site, or at list a link to it. It looks like it's probably contained in some div that is cutting it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/k0jwhqru/)

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;width=235&amp;layout=button_count&amp;action=like&amp;show_faces=false&amp;share=true&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:auto; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

I've changed the width to auto;

Comment: It is now completely visible, thanks. THe only problem is that the elements are aligned to the right and text-align: center; is not working.

Comment: Exactly... so, it was only a matter of width. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CláudioRibeiro In the second Fiddle I changed the width to 180px, display:block, margin:0 auto.

Answer (score 1):

Try a larger width .

width:80px;